# How to add attributes option to XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have problem with add attributes option.

I want edit Filezilla server xml to add new user. I found some script. This is some code from this script.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$user = $xml->Users->addChild('User');
$user->addAttribute('Name', $user_name); 
add_option($user,'Pass',md5($password));
```

Full script you can find [here](http://moshez.blogspot.cz/2013/02/php-filezilla-ftp-server-auto-create.html).

I have problem with `add_option` function. `("Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_option()")`

Comment: How are you calling `create_user`?

Comment: Can you add an example of $xmlfile ? There is no add_option function in php. Can you post a code of this function?

Comment: Have you actually included the whole script in your code? The function `add_option` is not built in, but defined below the code you cited in your question.

Comment: When I use Filezilla server program for add user. XML look like this. http://pastebin.com/4hrRh5rJ

Comment: "How are you calling create_user?" You see this in full script. It is in form below.

Comment: My goal is how to add option to attributes like you see in pastebin link I posted early.